# Linux transaction event logging

Tags: linux, jenkins, audit, svn-checkout

I would like to get some expert advise on following issues in the automated build and deployment implementation .

I have been part of the team responsible for automating the build and deployment of Warehouse product for the client.

We are using Jenkins for continuous integration and deployment model where SVN provide SCM solution.

The repository size is approximately 3GB or >100,000 files and each checkout causes huge transaction logs writing in Unix server. There was an incident where the server got rebooted due audit logging outstanding queue.

Can someone share your views around following?

1) Is there anyway to reduce the transaction events from Jenkins checkout
2) Is it mandatory to log each and every transaction on the server side where the file system size is really huge.

Any input is much appreciated.

Comment: You want to know if it is possible to tune your logging level with SVN?

Comment: No, its nothing to do with SVN or Jenkins logging.  If jenkins checking out 10 files as part of a build, there would be similar number of event getting logged by Linux audit process. Since my repository size is comparatively high audit demons can't manage such huge volume.